# Google Sheets Script Not Sending SMS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have added below script to my Google Sheet & configured it to send SMS upon form submit. However whenever we submit the form it is not sending any SMS to any number.

The script should pick up the users full name from the column what is Your full name & mobile number from what is your primary mobile number column

```
function createTriggers() {

  ScriptApp
  .getProjectTriggers()
  .forEach(function(trigger) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(trigger);
  });

  ScriptApp
  .newTrigger("triggerSMS")
  .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
  .onFormSubmit()
  .create();

}

function triggerSMS(e) {

  var response = e.namedValues;
  var message = response["What is Your Full Name"].toString() + " Thanks For Completing the form. Your Unique Code Is : " + response["unique ID"].toString();  
  var url="http://xxx.xxxx.org/api/sms/sendhttp.php";




  var payload = {
    "authkey" : "",
    "mobiles" : response["Primary Mobile Number"].toString(),
    "message" : encodeURIComponent(message),
    "sender"  : "BBBBB",
    "route"   : TRANS-5
  };

  var options = {
    "method"  : "MT",
    "payload" : payload,   
    "followRedirects" : true,
    "muteHttpExceptions": true
  };

  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

  Logger.log("e:  " + JSON.stringify(e));

}
```

Comment: You need to do some troubleshooting.  The easiest way to do that is with `Logger.log('what to log here')`  Then View the Logs.  Also, see the documentation at: [https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting?hl=en](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting?hl=en)  We don't know what questions you have in your Form, or what order they are in.  You could run your code to test the SMS part without submitting a Form.  Also, after running the code, choose View and Execution Transcript.  Is there an error and on what line?

Comment: I am getting below error message

Comment: I am getting below error message

I am getting below error message while running TriggerSMS function

TypeError: Cannot read property "namedValues" from undefined. (line 19, file "Code")

I have used log line for this error 
Logger.log("e:  " + JSON.stringify(e)); & got the below log

e
arguments
response
message
url
payload
options

 Object (1146933937) undefined Arguments (1146933964) undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined

Comment: The error: `Cannot read property "namedValues" from undefined` means that `e` the event object is `undefined`.  Which probably means that you are running the code from the code editor.  When running the code from the code editor, there is no event object passed into the function, and therefore it's undefined.  For testing purposes, create another function that calls `triggerSMS(e)` and pass in your own object with the values that would be in the event object.  See: [documentation at](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events?hl=en#form-submit)

Comment: Thanks Sourabh, am already calling that function in the script & there is no error when I run that however when i submit the form there is no SMS sent to my mobile number

.newTrigger("triggerSMS")

Comment: Jan 12, 2020, 4:54:22 PM Error TypeError: Cannot call method "toString" of undefined.
    at triggerSMS(form:20)